# ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

I wrote a text classification program. When I run the program it crashes with an error as seen in this screenshot:

[image: as seen in this screenshot]

> ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.

Here is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
import nltk, string, json
import numpy as np

def cleanText(corpus):
    reviews = []
    for dd in corpus:
        #for d in dd:
        try:
            words = nltk.word_tokenize(dd['description'])
            words = [w.lower() for w in words]
            reviews.append(words)
            #break
        except:
            pass
    return reviews

with open('C:\\NLP\\bad.json') as fin:
    text = json.load(fin)
    neg_rev = cleanText(text)

with open('C:\\NLP\\good.json') as fin:
    text = json.load(fin)
    pos_rev = cleanText(text)

#1 for positive sentiment, 0 for negative
y = np.concatenate((np.ones(len(pos_rev)), np.zeros(len(neg_rev))))

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(np.concatenate((pos_rev, neg_rev)), y, test_size=0.2)
```

The data I am using is available here:

1. [Bad](https://github.com/SilverYar/TransportDataMiner/blob/master/bad.json);
2. [Good](https://github.com/SilverYar/TransportDataMiner/blob/master/good.json)

How would I go about fixing this error?

Comment: Have you checked the `shape` of your concatenated reviews and your `y` variable?

Comment: hmm....., print (y) = [ ]

Comment: That explains your `n_samples=0` in the error. So work backward from there and figure out what actually comes out of your parsing in `pos_rev ` and `neg_rev`, because if you get no errors, it seems likely that the `len()` of each is `0`

Comment: df.shape gives output of Out[48]: (1, 67501)

Comment: Still the below line of code results in ValueError: x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.20,random_state=77,stratify=y)

Comment: OMG! Its python indentation going wrong. While refactoring and introducing a function this happened. Check this kind of error too, others.

Answer (score 15):

Got the same error: `ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.` 
In my case the path to the data was invalid. Check if paths to the loaded files exists or if the variables reading the files hold any data.

Answer (score 1):

I think below code snippets can help you in solving the issue.

```
ad_data=pd.read_csv("advertising.csv")from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x=ad_data[['Daily Time Spent on Site', 'Age', 'Area Income','Daily Internet Usage', 'Male']]
y=ad_data['Clicked on Ad']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the same error: `ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters`. The error occurs because of that the Data file is not found. In case you are using **jupyter** notebook you cannot used the **Dataframe** for defining X and y. So, using the **dataframe** to define x and y the problem is solved. In other case, it occurs due to it can't find the data. So check in the given path the data is exist.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. In my case, the problem was with the wrong file extension. I resolved this error just by changing the file extension. Thus, for this error: `ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.2 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters`, file extension can also be checked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the path was correct but I was using bert for text classification that is when I noticed the shape of the X and y variable  I was having only one sentence in input data so the model_selection was unable to split it so when I reshaped it into multiple sentences and it worked

Answer (score -1):

```
#x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, random_state=0)
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)
slr = LinearRegression()
slr.fit(x_train.reshape(-1,1), y_train)
```

I keep getting the error with n_samples=0, test_size=0.33 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters