# ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.1 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, project

here's the code:

```
trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.1, stratify=y_data)
```

here's the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-18-29e61f5e0a56> in <module>()
----> 1 trainX, testX, trainY, testY = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.1, stratify=y_data)

1 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _validate_shuffle_split(n_samples, test_size, train_size, default_test_size)
   1803             'resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the '
   1804             'aforementioned parameters.'.format(n_samples, test_size,
-> 1805                                                 train_size)
   1806         )
   1807 

ValueError: With n_samples=0, test_size=0.1 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: With n\_samples=0, test\_size=0.2 and train\_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043276/valueerror-with-n-samples-0-test-size-0-2-and-train-size-none-the-resulting-t)

Comment: Check the shape of your inputs `x_data` and `y_data `. Most likely one or both of them are empty.