# train_test_data_split function is showing problem

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression, prediction

I was trying to make a program to predict the runs made by a cricketer. I used a csv file for data made by me. The code is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#Data
data = pd.read_csv('Rohit Sharma.csv')

X = [['against','wickets','currentrun','weather','ball','over']]

Y = ['runsmade']

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.33, train_size=None, random_state=42)

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(x_train,y_train)

a = reg.predict(x_test)

print(a)

print(data)
```

But it showed an error:

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.33 and train_size=None, the resulting 
train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60043276/valueerror-with-n-samples-0-test-size-0-2-and-train-size-none-the-resulting-t

Comment: You have only one record in your training data (`X` and `Y`), which you are initializing just before the call to `train_test_split`. You are not using the data that you read from the CSV file at all. It looks like you meant to initialize `X` and `Y` from the data that you just loaded, but instead you're just putting some column names from the CSV in `X` and `Y` instead of the actual training data.

Comment: Where exactly does the error pop up? Please update your post with the full error trace, and *remove* any code that comes *after* the error (hence never executed, hence irrelevant to the issue) - see how to create a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Looks like you made an error while selecting the columns of the data. See below.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#Data
data = pd.read_csv('Rohit Sharma.csv')

X = data[['against','wickets','currentrun','weather','ball','over']].to_numpy()

Y = data['runsmade'].to_numpy()

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.33,  random_state=42)

reg = LinearRegression()

reg.fit(x_train,y_train)

a = reg.predict(x_test)

print(a)

print(data)
```